# How can I return null or bool from a function

Tags: c#

I have this function:

```
public bool GetBoolSetting(Settings setting)
{
    return int.Parse(GetStringSetting(setting)) == 0 ? false : true;
}
```

There is a problem in that `GetStringSetting(setting)` can return `null`, `"0"` or `"1"`.  When it returns a `null` I get an exception.

Is it possible for me to make the `GetBoolSetting` function return a null if this happens?

Comment: Do you really want it to return a null?  Think of all the things upstream affected by this.  Wouldn't it make more sense to return a false if the result of `GetStringSetting()` is null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the type of your method to [`Nullable<bool>`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-bool) and continue to your one linear statement like below:

```
public bool? GetBoolSetting(Settings setting)
{
    return GetStringSetting(setting) != null ? 
           int.Parse(GetStringSetting(setting)) != 0 : new bool?();//Or default(bool?)
}
```

You can also use [`default(bool?)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/default-keyword-in-generic-code) instead of `new bool?()` which returns the default value of Nullable bool that is null.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, like most languages, regular booleans are not nullable. You can however use [nullable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types) to get the result you want.

For example, if you want a method to be able to return `true`, `false`, or `null`, you specify a nullable bool as it's return type:

```
public bool? MyMethod()
{
    // Stuff
}
```

Notice the `?` after `bool`. That specifies that the boolean is *nullable*.

So in your case you could do:

```
public bool? GetBoolSetting(Settings setting)
{
    string myString = GetStringSetting(setting));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString))
        return null;
    return int.Parse(myString) != 0;
}
```

Be advised however, working with types like nullable bools is tricky. For example, if you try to pass this method's result to another method which takes a bool parameter, you will not be able to right away.

```
public void MyBoolMethod(bool parameter)
{
}

MyBoolMethod(MyMethod()); // This doesn't compile
```

You will have to cast your nullable boolean to a normal one, after of course making sure that it is **not** null:

```
MyBoolMethod((bool)MyMethod());
```

..or alternatively, decide on a default value for this case (what the `bool?` should become if it is null so that it can be used elsewhere), and convert it.

Example with `false` as the default:

```
bool newBool = MyMethod() ?? false;
```

An extra piece of advice, which has little to do with your question but I recommend you do. Instead of the unsafe `int.Parse`, which throws an exception if the provided string isn't valid, switch to [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public bool? GetBoolSetting(Settings setting)
{
    string myString = GetStringSetting(setting));
    int output = -1;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString) || !int.TryParse(myString, out output))
        return null;
    return output != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You likely want to use a nullable bool, like so:

```
public bool? GetBoolSetting(Settings setting)
{
    var s = GetStringSetting(setting);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return null;
    return int.Parse(s) == 0 ? false : true;
}
```

Or, if you'd rather treat null as false:

```
public bool GetBoolSetting(Settings setting)
{
    var s = GetStringSetting(setting);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return false;
    return int.Parse(s) == 0 ? false : true;
}
```

*Also, consider using `TryParse` rather than Parse.*

Answer (score 2):

You get the exception because `int.Parse` can't handle the `null` input. You have to check it before.

If you want to return null if `GetStringSetting` returns null, you need to change the return type to a `Nullable<bool>` (short by appending a question mark: `bool?`), e.g.:

```
public bool? GetBoolSetting(Settings setting)
{
  var strSetting = GetStringSetting(setting);
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strSetting))
    return null;
  return int.Parse(strSetting) == 0 ? false : true;
}
```

When using the return value, you have to check whether it has a value so that it is more complicated to handle:

```
var boolSetting = GetBoolSetting(...);
if (boolSetting.HasValue)
{
    // Check boolSetting.Value
}
else
{
     // Handle null value
}
```

For an overview of nullable data types, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/).

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool? GetBoolSetting(Settings setting)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(GetStringSetting(setting), out result))
        return null;
    return result == 0 ? false: true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to return `true` or `false` and get rid of strange `null` logic.

Using C# 7 syntax this can be made in one line:

```
public bool GetBoolSetting(Settings setting) => int.TryParse(GetStringSetting(setting), out int i) && i == 1;
```